# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.setStopTimeout(J)V

Tags: java, testng

While using Log and Reporter Log in TestNG getting this error. Any idea for the cause behind this error?

Any help would be helpful.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.setStopTimeout(J)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.destroy(OsProcess.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:448)
    at config.BaseClass.tearDown(BaseClass.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:425)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Apache Commons Exec jar.

Use for maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

For gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: '1.3'
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I was using the common exec but the older version i.e. 1.1.